# Finding the Constraint Equation for a String

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Original]

For the question above, the problem is finding the displacement of block1 after block2 is dropped. To proceed, we need a constraint equation relating $x_1, x_2$ and $\ddot{x_1}, \ddot{x_2}$. While I thought the equation was $L - c = x_1 + x_2$, the book instead offers $L + x_1 - x_2 = \text{constant}$ as the correct constraint equation. What is wrong with my intuition?

[image: Modified]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not distances from the origin of the coordinate system which could be to the left of the top block at the other end of the arrow with the label $X$, rather they are just the lengths of the bits of string as you show in the second diagram.
The book has $x_1$ and $x_2$ as distances from an origin.
Differentiating the two versions once shows this difference; the book version has both x's increasing whilst you version has your $x_2$ increasing whilst $x_1$ is decreasing.

**Update** as a result of a comment

I have assumed the the positions of the "front" ends of the blocks are $x_1$ and $x_2$, the length of block $M_2$ is $b$ and the length of the string is $L$

[image]

Of course you could get rid of $b$ by have $x_2$ referring to the "back" of block $M_2$.

Comment: What would $L$ represent in the case of distance from an origin?

Comment: What's the argument for using $x_1$ and $x_2$ as distances from an origin, versus using them as lengths of a string?

Comment: @Sentient  Both methods will work and what I tried to do was to show you how the book version came about.  I think that I would prefer the book method as then the signs of the velocities and the accelerations will be the same?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one "correct" equation of constraint because the question does not specify what co-ordinate system is to be used. I presume that the 2nd diagram indicates what co-ordinate system you are using.

Both equations are valid, depending on how the co-ordinates are defined. The book defines $x_1$ and $x_2$ as being in the same direction. You are defining $x_1$ and $x_2$ as having opposite directions. There is nothing "wrong" with your definition.

If you apply your co-ordinate system, you must use it consistently when you write the equations of motion. From the book definition you will get $\ddot x_1 = \ddot x_2$ whereas from your definition you will get $\ddot x_1 = -\ddot x_2$.

Comment: That presents a problem though, as when you substitute $\ddot{x_1}$ for $\ddot{x_2}$ -- $M\ddot{x_2} = W - T = W - M_1\ddot{x_1}$ -- and solve for displacement of block1, multiplying by negative 1 does not yield the same result.

Comment: @Sentient : The co-ordinate system must be applied consistently. The equations of motion are different for the 2 co-ordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance -- in your opinion, should I follow how the book solves problems or what my intuition says?

Comment: Use whichever system you are most comfortable with. Personally I find it least confusing to use a co-ordinate system in which the displacements $x_1, x_2$ and velocities $\dot x_1, \dot x_2$ are all increasing. In your co-ordinate system $x_1$ is decreasing and $\dot x_1, \ddot x_1$ are -ve, which could cause confusion.